# Configuring mod_wsgi daemon mode processes and threads

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-wsgi, wsgi, mpm-worker

I am planning to use `mpm_worker` or `mpm_event` with daemon mode of `mod_wsgi`. How to configure processes and threads of `WSGIDaemonProcess` directive for the  optimal performance of apache 2.4.9

Comment: Do you have any performance data about your application? Actual throughput and response times? In general such a question is better asked on the mod_wsgi mailing list.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton thanks for the reply(haven't expected you).I will ask on the mod_wsgi mailing list.